# simplest way to convert MySql timestamp to month/year with javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, date

I get this value from MySQL: `2014-01-11 14:11:10`
I would like to take that value and format it like so: `Jan 2014`
What is the simplest way to do so?

Comment: Depending on the scenario it may make more sense to do that in your SQL query with [`DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b %Y')`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate the `Date` object with the string given, like

```
var date = new Date("2014-01-11 14:11:10");
```

and then manipulate with that object. Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to transform it to the format you wish. However you can do this on your own.

In other words, you could do something like

```
var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

var dateString = "2014-01-11 14:11:10";

var date = new Date(dateString);

var msg = m_names[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear();
alert(msg);
```